# Ajax.BeginForm OnFailure Never Gets Called

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-mvc-ajax

I am using Ajax.BeginForm in my View, and providing an OnFailure handler in my .js, but it never gets called.  I've tried throwing an exception (throw new HttpException(500, "Internal Error")) in my controller and it never gets called.  ***The reason seems to be when I have customerrors turned on in the web.config.***  What I want to do, is handle any exceptions or errors in my controller, and pass them along to my the OnFailure handler in my .js file as if customerrors were turned off.  Is there any way to do this?

**SOLVED:**

Works even with customerrors turned on in web.config...

The way I handle this, is to set the **Response.StatusCode = 500** and append a Header to my response object **Response.AppendHeader("MyResponseHeader", "My Message");**

In my .js OnFailure handler...

```
function OnFailure(ajaxContext) {
    alert(ajaxContext.status); // 500
    alert(ajaxContext.getResponseHeader("MyResponseHeader"));  // "My Message"
}
```

Comment: @Shark the code is very simple if you know Ajax.BeginForm and providing AjaxOptions#OnFailure, etc. If I enable customerrors in web.config, and throw a 500 Http error in my controller, OnFailure .js handler never gets called.  If I simply turn customerrors off in web.config, OnFailure .js handler gets called.